# CSS bootstrap: list-group-item hover+selected

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, servicenow

I have the below script which I am trying to apply some CSS to, to overwrite the bootstrap defaults.

```
h2 class="sr-only">${Search Categories}</h2>

<div role="list" class="list-group">
      <a role="link" ng-class="{active: !data.t}" class="list-group-item" 
       ng-href="?id=search&q={{data.q}}" aria-label="${All search results}">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"/><span class="m-l-sm">${All}</span>
    </a>
      <a role="link" ng-repeat="source in data.searchSources | orderBy:'order'"
         ng-href="?id=search&t={{source.id}}&q={{data.q}}"
         ng-class="{active: data.t==source.id}"
         class="list-group-item" aria-label="{{source.name}} ${Search results}">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"/><span class="m-l-sm">{{source.name}}</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Current the issue currently is that when one of the links is selected its blue which is OOTB functionality for bootstrap list-group-item but I am having some trouble overwriting it.

I assume I need something like `a:focus {background-color: Whitesmoke}` or `list-group-item:focus ...` but neither of these seem to work.

What is the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

you should overwrite the `:visited` not `:hover`

ex :

```
a:visited {background-color: Whitesmoke}
```